# Error when creating tableview with multiple custom cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have encountered an error in `swift` when attempting to create a `tableview` made up of custom `cells` dependent upon a set of conditions.

Here is my code:

```
var tableData: [String] = []

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

// number of rows in table view
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tableData.count
}

// create a cell for each table view row
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let phonenocell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("phonecell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

    let pincell:SocialCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("socialcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SocialCell

    let fbcell:FacebookCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("facebookcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FacebookCell

    let snapcell:SnapchatCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("snapchatcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SnapchatCell

    let twitcell:TwitterCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("twittercell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TwitterCell

    let instacell:InstagramCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("instagramcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! InstagramCell


    if tableData.contains("Number") {
        return phonenocell
    }

    if tableData.contains("Social") {
        return pincell
    }

    if tableData.contains("Facebook") {
        return fbcell
    }

    if tableData.contains("Snapchat") {
        return snapcell
    }

    if tableData.contains("Twitter") {
        return twitcell
    }

    if tableData.contains("Instagram") {
        return instacell
    }

}
```

When attempting to build and run I get a build failed with the following fault:

```
"Missing Return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell'
```

I have been over and over my code but I honestly cannot see where I am going wrong...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you return when the last `if` -- `if tableData.contains("Instagram")` fails?

Comment: On each call of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are creating 6 cells, 5 for the trash and only one to use. That is very inefficient and expensive.

Comment: Can you show what your tableData looks like..and @vadian is right

Comment: tableData is an array, where I append an element based on the state of a switch. Here is the code for appending an example element to it: `@IBAction func switch1Toggled(sender: UISwitch) {
        if mySwitch1.on {
            fbTextBox.text = "Selected"
            dataArray.append("Facebook")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return cell for sure.
You already do in conditions, but in case none of your condition statements would success, your return call wouldn't be fired.

Appending, for example:

```
return phonenocell
```

to the end of the function, should be quick fix for your code. It ensures, that the function will return a cell (that is mandatory).

> My data source is the array tableData. This is constructed on the previous view as: `@IBAction func switch1Toggled(sender: UISwitch) { if mySwitch1.on { fbTextBox.text = "Selected" dataArray.append("Facebook")`

And this may be the main issue:

Assuming, that you choose 'facebook' and that you reload your tableView, every row will pass the first condition as it IS contained.
You should put this in your method:

```
//assuming your data source contains multiple members, and your numberOfRowsInSections... method return tableData.count, you need to get each item for each row:

let currentTag = tableData[indexPath.row]
if (currentTag == "something") { //e.g. Facebook
    let somethingcell:MySomethingCell =  ... 
    self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("somethingcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MySomethingCell
    return somethingcell
} else if {
    ...
} 

return emptycell //this line is just for the case, when no of your conditions will pass and you don't catch all the situations...
```

Comment: Hi, I have ensured there will be data in my array by not allowing the tableView to be accessed if the array is empty. Now all I am getting is the correct number of cells, but they are all showing the same data - the first cell "phonenocell".

Comment: OK, so you got rid of the previous error, right. And now you have next issue. So you could 1) check why 'tableData.contains("Number")' always return true. But it can have simple explanation. Your code does not distinguish your data source separately for individual rows. So that's why it returns always the first condition, because the data source is always the same for all cells. 2) post more code to see what is your data source

Comment: Hi, my data source is the array tableData. This is constructed on the previous view as: `@IBAction func switch1Toggled(sender: UISwitch) {
        if mySwitch1.on {
            fbTextBox.text = "Selected"
            dataArray.append("Facebook")`

Comment: Data source meaning the array I am using to check how many cells to contruct? I have just tried posting this but it is saying there are too many characters.

Comment: Your edited post has worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: So did my answer help you? :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe your array elements doesn't match the condition, it's better to return default value instead of ur conditions failed